# How to check what percent of all rows a row is within in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Lets say i have a table with x amount of rows. Now in this table i have a row that i want to find out on which percent of all rows ordered from the top this row exists in.

For example, finding out that row is within the top 27% of all rows or top 65% of all rows, etc.

Any help or input appreciated , thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table TempTable (id int, myValue int)

insert into TempTable(id, myValue) values (1, 5)
insert into TempTable(id, myValue) values (2, 15)
insert into TempTable(id, myValue) values (3, 20)
insert into TempTable(id, myValue) values (4, 50)
insert into TempTable(id, myValue) values (5, 60)

select
  RowNumber * 100.0 / TotalRows as Percentage1,
  (TotalRows - RowNumber) * 100.0 / TotalRows as Percentage2,
  myValue
from 
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by Id) AS RowNumber,
  COUNT(*) OVER() AS TotalRows,
  myValue
  FROM TempTable
) t
where myValue = 50
```

I'm not sure exactly which percentage you want so here are the two values you get from the above query.

```
Percentage1 Percentage2 myValue
80          20          50
```

Full SQLFiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b0e20/15/0

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you need in your query is to retrieve the row number, divide it by the total amount of rows ("x" in your question) and then multiply it by 100 to get the percentage.

```
Row Percentage = (Row Number / Total Row Count) * 100
```

For example:

```
Row Percentage = (6 / 32) * 100
Row Percentage = 18.75%
```

In order to get the row number with SQL Server, please, check [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

If I didn't get what you were asking, please, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to get a unique serial to identify each row. In following query which is sl. Then you will be able to find the position in percentage of a row among all rows.

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY accountNO)  AS sl
INTO #temp
FROM testTable

SELECT * FROM #temp

-- For sl = 1
SELECT ((1) * 100) /  (SELECT MAX(sl) FROM #temp) -- Within Top 4%

-- For sl = 5
SELECT ((5) * 100) /  (SELECT MAX(sl) FROM #temp) -- Within Top 20%

-- For sl = 10
SELECT ((10) * 100) /  (SELECT MAX(sl) FROM #temp) -- Within Top 40%

-- For sl = 15
SELECT ((15) * 100) /  (SELECT MAX(sl) FROM #temp) -- Within Top 60%

-- For sl = 20
SELECT ((20) * 100) /  (SELECT MAX(sl) FROM #temp) -- Within Top 80%

-- For sl = 25
SELECT ((25) * 100) /  (SELECT MAX(sl) FROM #temp) -- Within Top 100%

DROP TABLE #temp
```